# How to get logo to front layer

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am attempting to fix the Navigation bar for my website. I have the setup almost exactly how I would like it, but I want my logo to be in front of the bar. When I move it to the front by making the navbar z-index= -1 my links no longer work.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
    <body>

<header>

    <img src="Images/logo.png" height="50" width="50"/>

    <div class="mainnav">

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Write for Lakers Pulse</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Lakers Salaries</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Contact Us!</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

css

```
    nav a  {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 110%;
}

    li {
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
margin: 8% 4% -1% 4%;
padding: 1%;
}

.mainnav {
background: #4A2583;
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0.6;
z-index: 1;
margin: -10%;
}

a:hover {
color: #F5AF1B;
}

a:active {
color:blue;
}

img {
padding-left:10px;
z-index: 5;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to img css. This stops the element catching any click on it at all, but instead just lets the event fall through to the element below it thereby allowing your links to work.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I added it right below the z-index: 5;

Comment: Even with putting the z-index for the mainnav at 1 and at 5 for the image, the image is behind the nav bar. 
The only way I can get the image to the front is to make the z index of the mainnav to -1, which is when the hover and links stop working

Comment: Try giving your image a position: absolute; as well as the pointer-events:none; z-index:5 and get rid of z-index from the nav bar.

Comment: position:absolute seemed to be the key! Thank you so much!